# A Theory Entailing a Logical Equivalence of Two Formulas in FOL

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In FOL we say two formulas $\phi$ and $\psi$ are *logically equivalent* iff  $\phi\vDash\psi$ and $\psi\vDash\phi$.

My question is: What does it mean to say that a theory $T$ entails that $\phi$ and $\psi$ are logically equivalent? $T \vDash (\phi\vDash\psi \text{ and } \psi\vDash\phi)$

Can we say it means $T, \phi\vDash\psi$ and $T, \psi\vDash\phi$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last line is right: "$\varphi$ and $\psi$ are $T$-equivalent" *(which I think is the clearest way to phrase it in natural language)* means "$T,\varphi\models\psi$ and $T,\psi\models\varphi$."

*(Meanwhile, "$T\models (\varphi\models\psi \wedge\psi\models\varphi)$" doesn't actually mean anything - we can't "iterate $\models$.")*

However, there are a couple other (equivalent) ways to formulate this:

- By the [completeness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem), that's equivalent to "$T,\varphi\vdash\psi$ and $T,\psi\vdash\varphi$" - that is, we can replace *semantic entailment* with *proof*.
- By the [deduction theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem), that's equivalent to "$T\vdash\varphi\leftrightarrow\psi$."
- The deduction theorem also has a *(much simpler to prove)* semantic counterpart: it's easy to show that $T,\theta\models\eta$ iff $T\models\theta\rightarrow \eta$, and it follows that ($T,\theta\models\eta$ and $T,\eta\models\theta$) iff $T\models\theta\leftrightarrow\eta$. So finally, yet another equivalent way to express "$\varphi$ and $\psi$ are $T$-equivalent" - and in my opinion the snappiest really - is $$"T\models\varphi\leftrightarrow\psi."$$ Indeed,it's this last one that I consider the *definition of* "$\varphi$ and $\psi$ are $T$-equivalent," and I'd consider the equivalences with the other three versions to be (easily proved) theorems.